# Amazon cloud setup for receiving and sending images and videos

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I need some advise regarding my amazon cloud setup.

I have a servicestack api which recieves streams in form of images and videos, and these needs to be saved somewhere. The same api also delivers these streams to clients (website, apps etc.)

This means that a lot of data is being transferred over Internet and saved to disk somewhere.

What is the best setup here when looking at pricing? I've tried the amazon cloud pricing calculator, but its difficult to figure out all the numbers.

I was thinking....
- Normal ec2 instance for hosting api
- S3 bukcet for saving images and videos
- CloudFront for delivering images and videos

Is there a better and cheaper approach?
I was thinking that data transfer and disk space would be a huge cost in this setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think amazon s3 is very good for saving images and videos.The pricing based on data transferred "in" to and "out" of Amazon S3.Pay only for what you use. There is no minimum fee. We charge less where our costs are less, and prices are based on the location of your Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: But is it the best approach when the ec2 instance with the api endpoint will be transferring a big amount of data per nonth? The data needs to be transferred before i can save it.